# Python function fails when passing a variable instead of a number

Tags: python, function, variables, arguments

Can someone please explain why this is not working?  When I use a number as the argument it works but when I use a variable that holds a number it does not work.

```
def convertF2C(f):
    c = (f - 32) / 1.8
    return c


num = input("Enter a number to convert:")
print("you entered:",num)
c = convertF2C(**num**)    \\If I use a number as the argument it works.
print(c)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your argument from `str` to `float`

```
num = float(input("Enter a number to convert:"))
```

The return type of `input` is `str`, which is not a numeric type, so you cannot perform arithmetic until you convert it.

Comment: Thank you sooooo much.  I'm so excited about coding.  Been putting it off for years!  It worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your code and tested it , now it's work.

```
def convertF2C(f):
    c = (f - 32) / 1.8
    return c


num = input("Enter a number to convert:")
print("you entered:",num)
c = convertF2C(num)    #\\If I use a number as the argument it works.
print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some thing like this below

```
def convertF2C(f):
    c = (f - 32) / 1.8
    return c


num = int(raw_input("Enter a number to convert:"))
print("you entered:",str(num))
c = convertF2C(num)
print(c)
```